# Sample size required for a given margin of error in sample mean when population standard deviation is not known

Tags: mean, sample-size

I have trained a regressor to predict the revenue generated when users click on an ad impression. Only few clicks eventually lead to positive revenue. As such, I have used the Tweedie regression in XGBoost to train the model.

My question is, how many samples do i need to train on for a given ad to have confidence in its prediction? Is there a way to compute the margin of error?

I am familiar with computing the margin of error for classification tasks (sample *proportions*). However, I am not sure how to do this for sample *mean*.

When I searched online, most texts ([for example](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-the-margin-of-error-for-a-sample-mean/)) state that one needs to know thee *population* standard deviation in order to compute the margin of error. But that itself is unknown here.

My idea is that, I can define a margin of error (say 1% of sample mean) and see if the given sample size gives me a margin of error less than this threshold. I can use this formulation to compute a minimum sample size.

I don't have a formal stats background. So, might be totally off here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sample standard deviation to estimate the population standard deviation (using the Bessel correction, for example), and then compute a standard $ t $-statistic with this information. Under assumptions of normality, the distribution of the test statistic is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), so you can use standard $ p $-value tables to create a hypothesis test, which will give you a confidence interval for the population mean given the sample mean.

If the assumption of normality is not met, then depending on your sample size you might have to be careful; but the estimator is asymptotically normal, so as long as the true distribution is not too far from a normal (doesn't have high kurtosis relative to the sample size and so forth) you can reliably use these $ t $-statistic tables to get confidence intervals, i.e. margins of error.